# How to add a cell to a table and then wrap after N columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a single column table with a header. When some other element on the page is selected, an identifier is dynamically added as a new row:

```
Identifiers
789654    
321478    
963258    
741825    
917382    
147896
```

This works fine, but it can sometimes make the page quite long. It has been proposed that we add columns initially rather than rows and then create a new row once we have reached N columns. So for N=5:

```
Identifiers
789654 321478 963258 741825 917382    
147896
```

I could write Javascript to parse the table contents each time but is there an easier way?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wycott/o2vq4hnr/)

Comment: Use a flexbox instead of a table. In fact, it doesn't seem you should've been using a table in the first place

Comment: "*...is there an easier way?*" - possibly, but without seeing your code (and your HTML) how are we supposed to offer any specific help or guidance? Please, re-read the "[MCVE]" guidelines regarding the code you should add to your question in order for us to realistically help you.

Comment: Post some code that you are currently using to add a row.

Comment: OK, I've added a fiddle to the Q.

Comment: @DavidThomas Try re-reading the article yourself. This *isn't* about a problem with the code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit more JQuery-fu solves it but there must be a better way!

```
var x = 0;
var y = 0;

AddThis('012345');
AddThis('678901');
AddThis('123456');
AddThis('789012');
AddThis('345678');
AddThis('901234');

function AddThis(ident)
{       
    if (x === 0 && y === 0)
    {
        $('#wibble tr:last').after(Rowify(GetId()));        
    }
    else
    {    
        if (x === 5)
        {   
            y++;           
            $('#wibble tr:last').after(Rowify(GetId()));
            x = 0;            
        }
    }
    $('#' + GetId()).append(Cellify(ident));
    x++;
}

function GetId()
{
    return 'r' + y;
}

function Rowify(id) {
    return "<tr id='" + id + "'></tr>";
}

function Cellify(data) {
    return '<td>' + data + '</td>';
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wycott/o4Lo1cx1/)